# Show unique array data for one column but multiple items for other column

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a loop that's showing a contract and a location.

It's looping through and getting the contract name and the location per row. There are duplicate contracts in the rows so I only want to show one then list all the locations underneath it.

I know I can use something like `array_unique();` to strip out the duplicates but not sure how to integrate that into my loop.

**How can I show all the unique contracts and show multiple locations tied to that contract?**

```
  <?php
  // Find all locations tied to the current logged in user.
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'locations',
    'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'       => 'regional_operations_manager',
            'value'     => $user->id,
            'compare'   => 'LIKE'
        ),
    ),
  );
  // query
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

  <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
      <?php $clients[] = array('contract' => get_field('contract'), 'location' => get_the_title()); ?>
    <?php endwhile;
  endif;

  // Sort them alphabetically and only show unique locations.
  //$contracts = array_unique( $contracts );
  //sort($contracts);
  foreach ( $clients as $key => $row ) { ?>
    <?php echo $contract[$key] = $row['contract']; ?><br />
    <?php echo $location[$key] = $row['location']; ?><br />
  <?php } ?>
```

This is some of the data:

1. Adidas
   Viables 3 Viables Business
2. Aldi
   Bridgend
3. Aldi
   Pembroke Dock
4. Aldi
   Haverfordwest

The first word is the contract, the rest after that is the location.

I want to only show one "Aldi" with locations 2, 3 and 4 underneath it for example. So one unique contract can have multiple locations.

Comment: Looks like you're using wordpress. Check https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query and search for `groupby` and `orderby` You want to change your wp_query to get the right results in the order you want it.

Comment: @caramba I've added what it's really doing above that block of code. It's finding the current logged in user, then finding all the CPT's `locations` that are tied to that user. I don't know if I could still do it can I?

Comment: @caramba Just updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not so fluent in wordpress but sure you could solve the order part via the [wp_query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Either way, you could build your `$clients` array like so:

```
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ):
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
      <?php $clients[get_field('contract')]['locations'] = []; ?>
      <?php array_push($clients[get_field('contract')]['locations'], get_the_title()); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

That will create the `$clients` array looking something like this where you can foreach over it...

```
<?php

$clients['Adidas']['locations'] = [];
array_push($clients['Adidas']['locations'], 'Viables 3 Viables Business');

$clients['Aldi']['locations'] = [];
array_push($clients['Aldi']['locations'], 'Bridgend');
array_push($clients['Aldi']['locations'], 'Pembroke Dock');
array_push($clients['Aldi']['locations'], 'Haverfordwest');

foreach ($clients as $contract => $locations ) {
    echo 'Contract: ' . $contract . "\n";
    sort($locations['locations']); // this will sort the locations alphabetically
    foreach ($locations['locations'] as $location ) {
        echo ' - Location: ' . $location . "\n";
    }
}
```

Result looks like so:

```
Contract: Adidas
 - Location: Viables 3 Viables Business
Contract: Aldi
 - Location: Bridgend
 - Location: Haverfordwest
 - Location: Pembroke Dock
```

[You can play with it here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8c42b42a8b464e32735ef3d989a6aca82cffeaf6)

Comment: @Rob **check the while loop**, there are not hardcoded names in there! the ones which are is just to give an example how the data will look like

Comment: Sorry, it works!! It's been a long few hours of banging my head on the desk!! Thanks again.